# LWE with a low rank matrix

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, cryptography

Consider the decision LWE setting, where we have to distinguish between $(A, As + e)$ and $(A, u)$, for a randomly chosen $m \times n$ matrix $A$, an $n \times 1$ secret vector $s$, an $m \times 1$ Gaussian secret vector $e$, and a randomly chosen $m \times 1$ vector $u$.

In [many places](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2013/78810018/78810018.pdf), a "lossy version" of the setting is considered, where $A$ is replaced with a randomly sampled low rank matrix. How low can the rank of the matrix be for the setting to still be secure? I did not find any explicit calculations that talk about how the runtime of the distinguisher scales with the rank of $A$.

Comment: FYI, Chris Pikert, and Mark are answering such questions on [cryptography.se]